# path to a page in another bundle

Tags: symfony, routes

I have 2 bundles : Login and Redirect:
in the index page of Login bundle i want to make a link to a page in the Redirect bundle, I am new in symfony and I had a routes problem:
Here are my 2 routes files :

```
login_login_homepage:
pattern:  /login
defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:index }

login_login_signup:
pattern:  /signup
defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup }

login_login_logout:
pattern:  /logout
defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:logout }
login_login_home:
pattern:  /home
defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:home }

2nd:
gs_redirect_crud:
resource: "@GSRedirectBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.yml"
prefix:   /
```

what I made in the twig file

```
 <a href="{{path('gs_redirect_crud')}}" >Add New Redirection</a>
```

but i had this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "gs_redirect_crud" does not exist.") in LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig at line 11.
```

any help guys ???????

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously true, because there's no defined

```
"gs_redirect_crud"
```

route.

2nd instruction includes set of route definitions described in

```
@GSRedirectBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.yml
```

file. Try to find correct route names in that file.

Comment: sow hat should I do ?

Comment: As i said above, u sould open 
@GSRedirectBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.yml and find route  for the link that u want to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can set gs_redirect_crud as a global route.

**Code** to symfony-application / app / config / **config.yml**:

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

**Code** to symfony-application / app / config / **routing.yml**:

*1st option:*

```
gs_redirect_crud:
resource: "@GSRedirectBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.yml"
prefix:   /
```

*2nd option:*

```
gs_redirect_crud:
resource: "@GSRedirectBundle/Controller/"
type: annotation
prefix:   /
```